# Nested Promises: Creating N promises based on array

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have N workspaces. The number N is dynamic.

Every workspace has to execute a few pre-defined queries.

What I am currently doing is looping through an array of workspaces(`Synchronously`) and executing all the queries using `Promise.all()` (which is `asynchronous`).

**Goal**: What I need is to run all the queries for all the workspaces asynchronously. So I want to get rid of the loop to go thru each workspace. The ideal result would be an array of array. For example, if there are 3 workspaces and 2 queries the result would be `[[q1, q2], [q1,q2], [q1,q2]]` each q1 and q2 are the results for every workspace.

Below is the sample code:

```
async function fetchingWorkspaceLogs (workspaceId) {
  // Defining q1QueryString, q2QueryString so on...
  // for azure "loganalytics" reader.
  const [q1Result, q2Result, q3Result] = await Promise.all([
    logAnalyticsReader.query(
      q1QueryString,
      workspaceId
    ),
    logAnalyticsReader.query(
      q2QueryString,
      workspaceId
    ),
  ])
// return some promises
}

// Parse all workspaces for query
for (let j = 0; j < workspaceIdList.length; j++) {
  workspaceId = workspaceIdList[j]
  const queryResults = await fetchingWorkspaceLogs(workspaceId)
  q1QueryResults = queryResults[0]
  q2QueryResults = queryResults[1]
}
```

How can I create another promise object to make it async?

Feel free to ask if you need anything else to get more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can `map()` that workspaces array into `Promises` array and wrap it with `Promise.all`.

The below code is "pseudo" to make the point.

If it not reflects your situation, I'll probably need more information.

```js
async function fetchingWorkspaceLogs (workspaceId) {
  const [q1Result, q2Result] = await Promise.all([
    Promise.resolve(`param1: ${workspaceId}`),
    Promise.resolve(`param2: ${workspaceId}`),
  ]);
  // In this example, the function returns the result to make the point of returning Promise with the information
  return Promise.resolve([q1Result, q2Result]);
}

const workspaceIdList = ['workspace1', 'workspace2', 'workspace3'];

(async () => {
  const result = await Promise.all(
    workspaceIdList.map(workspace => fetchingWorkspaceLogs(workspace))
  );

  console.log(result);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped!

Comment: My pleasure :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

you need to use .map() function.